# How to convert from degrees to radians in 2 out of 3 columns of a table?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table (40000 x 3) of 3 columns and 40000 rows, one column is not related to the problem, and the other two columns contain numerical values in degrees. How can I covert all of the values in columns 2 and 3 from radians to degrees?

Note: DF4 is the name of the table. latitude and longitude are the names of the two columns.

I've tried creating a function (deg_to_rad()), then I've assigned a variable to column 2 and another variable to column 3. I've then attempted to call the function with the name of the variable as the argument. I did this twice for each column. It works in the sense that it does convert the values to radians but I can't put the two columns back together into a table with the third column.

Is there an easier way to achieve this goal?

Also, is it possible to use lambda instead?

This is the code I've written:

```
def deg_to_rad(dr):
    return (dr*math.pi)/180

DEG_TO_RAD_ATTEMPT_LATITUDE = DF4['latitude']
DEG_TO_RAD_ATTEMPT_LONGITUDE = DF4['longitude']
deg_to_rad((DEG_TO_RAD_ATTEMPT_LATITUDE))
deg_to_rad((DEG_TO_RAD_ATTEMPT_LONGITUDE))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC you can just do:

```
DF4['latitude'] = deg_to_rad(DF4['latitude'])
DF4['longitude'] = deg_to_rad(DF4['longitude'])
```

You're not assigning back the result of your function

you take a reference here:

```
DEG_TO_RAD_ATTEMPT_LATITUDE = DF4['latitude']
```

you then pass it to your function which will return the result but this isn't being assigned to anything, nor is it modifying the passed in column

Also you can use [`np.deg2rad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.deg2rad.html) to achieve the same:

```
import numpy as np

DF4['latitude'] = np.deg2rad(DF4['latitude'])
DF4['longitude'] = np.deg2rad(DF4['longitude'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you are using Pandas.

To add a new column, you do

```
df['col_name'] = deg_to_rad(some_val)
```

NumPy provides vectorised functions for converting values from degrees and radians and vice versa, so you don't actually need to define your own.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the table is like:

```
x, lat, long
.    .    .
.    .    .
```

Wrap the function in lambda and use apply().

```
df['lat'] = df['lat'].apply(lambda x: logic)
df['long'] = df['long'].apply(lambda x: logic)
```

However, if the main goal to do this to calculate the distance you can use **Haversine Formula**, to calculate without this conversion.

Read [this](https://pypi.org/project/haversine/)